# Unable to launch Read The Docs in docker

Tags: docker, read-the-docs

I'm having several issues with RTD install and dependencies so decided to use the official RTD docker image.

After installing docker I do as said the in the official RTD docker repository:

```
docker pull readthedocs/build:latest
```

After I run an instance of it:

```
docker run -itd --name myreadthedocs01 readthedocs/build
```

When I run the command *docker ps -a* the container shows up and running.

If i do *docker inspect myreadthedocs01* I get it's IP addr: 172.17.0.2 which I can ping.

Yet no http service appears to be running, no Ports are show in the *docker ps -a* command, curl does not output anything. I've tried using -p 8000:8000 (default RTD port) and -p 80:80 with no success.

I need a docker instance of RTD up and running accessible from the network. How can I solve this?

Comment: You are launching a container to build the docs. It does not run any server. You can exec into the container and get started with the build.

Comment: So basically this container only builds the documentation with sphinx (or other) makes the structure of the html/pdf/epub/etc but it won't run any instance of RTD right?

Comment: Yes. It just builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has stated on comments by franklinsijo, the docker container only builds the documentation, it doesn't have a webserver to show it. It's a build instance of sphynx not RTD *per se*

Comment: The first line of the [documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/buildenvironments.html) supports this.